# Tree floating divs height 100%, one fixed width - middle overlows

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to have a div with fixed width (1000px) in the center, one div floats left and fills the background, another one fills the background on the right side. All have 100% height.

```
<div id="left">
</div>
<div id="right">
</div>
<div id="main">
   Text
</div>
```

The css:

```
html, body{
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
width:100%;

padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#left{
position: relative;
width:50%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:-500px;
float:left;
}
#right{
position:relative;
width:50%;
height:100%;
top:0;
right:-500px;
float:right;
}

#main{
width: 1000px;
margin:auto;
}
```

The problem is that content breaks out of the middle div. It is still in the div, but under the other ones.

How can i fix it, that the content is shown on top of the middle div?

For better imagination: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eluGt

Answer (score 0):

Try this...i think its what you're after

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
      <head>
       <title>Failing Divs</title>
     </head>
    <body>
        <div id="left">
        </div>
      <div id="main">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
        </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

...

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;

    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

p{
 padding:5px; 
}

#left{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    background: black;
}
#right{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    background: blue;
}

#main{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
    background: gray;
}
```

Comment: nope, i actually want a div with 1000 px fixed width in the center, and two divs that fill the left and right background

Comment: Well to do that, you cant really use percentages for the left and right div as they would be uneven. If you are making it to fit your specific screen, just get the width, take 1000 from that and split what is left to define the width of the left and right div...what i did does solve the text being at the bottom tho :D